# Notepad++ увеличение значения на 1 при замене

Tags: notepad++

**Дано**

Имеется файл xml на 5000-10000 документов
Надо в документе поменять только номер (docNum="272")

**Что требуется**

Нужно заменить (docNum="272") так, чтобы все последующие замены увеличивались на 1

(docNum="272")
(docNum="273")
(docNum="274")

Comment: А разве он умеет вычислять что-то?

Comment: Да что б я знал! Просто есть регулярные выражения, вот и подумал может быть он может так заменить

Comment: Они то есть, но ни где нет информации, чтобы при замене можно было делать вычисления в Notepad++. В PSPad я тоже не нашел возможности вычислений при заменах через регулярки.

Comment: @Drimoos: Всё это возможно с PythonScript.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как повысить значения в каждой строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/769943/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)