# Как повысить значения в каждой строке

Tags: xml, notepad++

Есть xml с параметрами:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Parametrs> 
    <op id = "1212" version = "100" />
    <op id = "1222" version = "104" />
    <op id = "1232" version = "103" />
    <op id = "1252" version = "133" />
    <op id = "1262" version = "112" />
    <op id = "1292" version = "101" />
    <op id = "1812" version = "101" />
    <op id = "1612" version = "101" />
    <op id = "1292" version = "105" />
    <op id = "1912" version = "105" />
    <op id = "1762" version = "106" />
    <op id = "1892" version = "107" />
    <op id = "1142" version = "102" />
    <op id = "1582" version = "133" />
</Parametrs>
```

Как повысить значения version на 1 в каждой строке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML файлы удобно модифицировать при помощи xslt-преобразований. Вот преобразование для Вашего случая

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="@version">
    <xsl:attribute name="version">
      <xsl:value-of select=". + 1"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

зажми Shift и выделяй правой кнопкой, затем держи Ctrl и жми вверх